# Read data from multiple .txt files to plot on one graph in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The python code below works for plotting data (two columns separated by a space) from 3 .txt files. However, I would like to plot data from more text files located in the same folder. Is there a way that I can read the data from all .txt files in the folder and plot them all on the same graph?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('10mm.txt',sep='\s+',header=None)
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

x1 = data[0]
y1 = data[1]
plt.plot(x1, y1, label = "10 mm")

data = pd.read_csv('20mm.txt',sep='\s+',header=None)
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

x2 = data[0]
y2 = data[1]
plt.plot(x2, y2, label = "20 mm")

data = pd.read_csv('30mm.txt',sep='\s+',header=None)
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

x3 = data[0]
y3 = data[1]
plt.plot(x3, y3, label = "30 mm")

plt.xlim(0.15)
plt.ylim(0)
plt.xlabel('x - axis')
plt.ylabel('y - axis')
plt.title('')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can either manually create a list of all the filenames or use the `os` module to read the directory they're stored in to create the list, then iterate over it with a `for` loop, feeding each filename into a function that reads the CSV into a temp dataframe and plots the points on your graph.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Have you consulted the Matplotlib documentation? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the files in your directory and if it ends with `.txt`, you can load the data and plot it. Note that `pd.read_csv()` already returns a DataFrame so you don't need to convert `data` to a DataFrame again.

You have to replace `directory` with your `directory` path.

```
import os

# Replace this directory with your own directory. 
directory = 'C:/Users/admin'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".txt") :
        data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\s+', header=None)
        # data = pd.DataFrame(data) # This step is redundant
        plt.plot(data[0], data[1], label = filename.split('.')[0])
    else:
        continue

plt.xlim(0.15)
# Rest of the code
plt.show()
```

Comment: You don't need use use a raw string literal for the directory path if you're using `/` instead of `\`. You also don't need the trailing slash (either direction), as `os.listdir()` doesn't require it, and you're not concatenating paths anywhere.

Comment: No problem. Technically, you (from the OP's lead) don't need to assign temp `x` and `y` variables. `plt.plot(data[0], data[1], ...)`

Comment: @MattDMo Yes, you are right. It can be shortened. I don't know the data type but I think one can simply also write `plt.plot(*data)`

Comment: I don't *think* that works for dataframes, but I could be wrong...

Comment: Many thanks @Sheldore and MattDMo for your help! The code works perfectly :-)